# What does a confidence interval tell you about the relationship between two things?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, ratio, confidence-interval

So I have found a 95% confidence interval for the odds ratio of  developing cancer with vitamin A intake. My sample odds ratio was 1.1667 with a 95% confidence interval of (0.5394, 2.5227).

I am then asked what this interval can tell me about the relationship between vitamin A intake and cancer death. But I am unsure what I could say and what it is actually telling me.

Is there is a strong relationship between the two? A weak one? Nothing?